# how can do a control drag with a touch screen

Tags: windows-10, windows-tabletpc

Is there a way to perform a control drag with a touch screen?
For example, when I need to copy rather than move.

Similarly, I would like to simulate a control shift drag. How would I do that?

Comment: You might call up the on-screen keyboard, set Control to be On, then do the drag.

Comment: Good. I have put it in an answer for being accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done this way :

- Call up the on-screen keyboard
- In the on-screen keyboard, click the <kbd>Control</kbd> key so it becomes On
- Execute the drag operation

You may also use the above for the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key